# How do I change fonts depending on language in same paragraph?

Tags: javascript, css, unicode

I'm working on a WordPress website and there is already a lot of content written in both Chinese and English. So it's not a normal multilingual site where you get redirected to a Chinese version of the site and and English version.

I tried using @fontface to detect a unicode range

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'NotoSans';
  src: url('fonts/chinese/NotoSansCJKtc-Thin.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: 200;
  unicode-range: U+4E00-U+9FFF, U+3400-U+4DBF, U+2B740–U+2B81F; /* CJK unicode */
}
```

and then use

```
body { 
  font-family: "NotoSans", "Nunito";
}
```

But then all text, Chinese and English, uses the Noto Sans font. I only want the Chinese text to use Noto Sans. Where am I going wrong with the above - Should it just not apply the Noto Sans font where unicode-range is determined and fall back onto Nunito font for outside that range?

---

Alternatively,

Or should I try using javascript to detect unicode-range and apply a span with specific class? But would that wrap every character in the span?

```
if(/^[\u4e00-\u9faf]+$/ || /^[\u3400-\u4dbf]+$/ || /^[\u2b740-\u2b81f]+$/)) {
  // add span around
}
```

Here's an example text:

> 協辦單位：黃霑書房、Every Life Is A Song 一個人一首歌

so then I want,

```
<span class="chinese-font">協辦單位：黃霑書房</span>、Every Life Is A Song <span class="chinese-font">一個人一首歌</span>
```

Is that a better solution? How would I write the javascript code?